# Matching everything between html <body> tags using PHP

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I have a script that returns the following in a variable called $content

```
<body>
<p><span class=\"c-sc\">dgdfgdf</span></p>
</body>
```

I however need to place everything between the body tag inside an array called matches

I do the following to match the stuff between the body tag

```
preg_match('/<body>(.*)<\/body>/',$content,$matches);
```

but the $mathces array is empty, how could I get it to return everything inside the body tag

Comment: check this note about using regex for parsing html: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should not use regular expressions to parse HTML.

Your particular problem in this case is you need to add the [DOTALL modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) so that the dot matches newlines.

```
preg_match('/<body>(.*)<\/body>/s', $content, $matches);
```

But seriously, use an HTML parser instead. There are so many ways that the above regular expression can break.

Answer (score 12):

[Don't try to process html with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)! Use [PHP's builtin parser](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) instead:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($string);
$bodies = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body');
assert($bodies->length === 1);
$body = $bodies->item(0);
for ($i = 0; $i < $body->children->length; $i++) {
    $body->remove($body->children->item($i));
}
$string = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: I know it's an old question and answer but, this is a much better answer than the accepted solution

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you don't have DOMDocument installed, try this

Step 1. Download [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Step 2. Read the documentation about how to [use its selectors](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find)

```
require_once("simple_html_dom.php");
$doc = new simple_html_dom();
$doc->load($someHtmlString);
$body = $doc->find("body")->innertext;
```

Comment: FYI: Back then it had a memory leak and would kill the entire request when dealing with large pages.  Hopefully it's fixed by now.