# PHP get tags inside body and remove the text content inside of each tag

Tags: php, regex

I want to grab all contents inside body.

```
<html>
<head><title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="dummy">Your contents</div>
<p class="p">Paragraph</p>
<div id="example">My Content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the final result that I want :

```
<div id="dummy"></div>
<p class="p"></p>
<div id="example"></div>
```

Not like this :

```
<div id="dummy">Your contents</div>
<p class="p">Paragraph</p>
<div id="example">My Content</div>
```

Comment: Why does it have to be with a regex?

Comment: You should REALLY consider dropping regex and go the route you should with a parser. For example PHP's DOMDOcument http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matching everything between html <body> tags using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182829/matching-everything-between-html-body-tags-using-php)

Comment: yes using preg, i don't want use dom document, @BookOfZeus see the result i want, not only get body contents, but clean content inside all tags in body

Comment: @oknoorap: That's exactly why you don't want to use regex...

Comment: @oknoorap You should have explicitly mentioned that you want to remove the text content inside of each tag. This totally changes the question. Every answer to your question becomes now incorrect and will be voted down...

Comment: The problem is that we three who posted a solution before your edit (assuming that the body content should be extracted unchanged) will be voted down now. Just be more clear when asking a question in the future to avoid misunderstanding, please.

Comment: @leemes : Can't you delete your answers? Is there a minimal reputation for that?

Comment: @greg0ire I did so, but I don't think there's rep for that...

Comment: @greg0ire I got the negative rep undone. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$content = '<html>
<head><title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="dummy">Your contents</div>
<p class="p">Paragraph</p>
<div id="example">My Content</div>
</body>
</html>';

preg_match('/(?:<body[^>]*>)(.*)<\/body>/isU', $content, $matches);
$bodycontent = $matches[1];
echo htmlspecialchars($bodycontent);
preg_match_all('/<[^>]*>/isU', $bodycontent, $matches2);
$tags = implode("",$matches2[0]);
echo htmlspecialchars($tags);
```

Comment: htmlspecialchars was to show the result, only. wondering though, why i got voted down. it might not be the best way to do it, but obviously it was what oknoorap asked for...

Answer (score 2):

Although this would work :

```
if (preg_match('%<(body)[^>]*>(.*)<\s*/\1\s*>%s', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[2];
}
```

I wouldn't recommend it. You have way better tools for this job with php. For example using [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/html-parsing-and-screen-scraping-with-the-simple-html-dom-library/) parser:

```
# create and load the HTML  
include('simple_html_dom.php');  
$html = new simple_html_dom();  
$html->load("<html>
               <head><title>Test</title></head>
               <body>
                 <div id="dummy">Your contents</div>
                 <p class="p">Paragraph</p>
                 <div id="example">My Content</div>
               </body>
            </html>");  


# get an element representing the body  
$element = $html->find("body");
```

**Edit:**

Since you insist...

```
$result = preg_replace('%(<(div)[^>]*>).*<\s*/\2\s*>%', '\1</\2>', $subject);
```

This will remove the contents of a div tag. You can exchange the div tag with other tags as well. Although I really do not know where you are getting at with this and I **don't** recommend it.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want using dom, i want use preg match or preg replace

Comment: This assumes the HTML code to have correct syntax. The sad fact is, that you simply cannot guarantee this for arbitrary web pages, even if they render "correctly" (= as assumed by the web page author) in most browsers.

Comment: no, I mean, my question is only example not complex as my work.

Comment: @oknoorap I did provide two solutions I believe.

Comment: @FailedDev yes, but the final result I want is clean content inside tags.

Comment: @oknoorap Did you even try my regex?

Comment: yes, your code will return <div id="dummy">Your contents</div> not <div id="dummy"></div> , and I want pure PHP I won't using simple dom helper

Comment: @oknoorap Not possible with a single regex I am afraid. This is exactly why you should use a parser. You can do this with some very complicated regex, however in the end you would be creating a parser. So why just don't use one?

Comment: @FailedDev can I use looping regex? sorry it doesn't matter if I'm using multiple statement. Its possible? . Thanks for your help

Comment: @oknoorap You could use whatever you want. This is not the point. The point is you will be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @FailedDev okay, how to clean inside contents? of <div id="dummy">Your contents</div> and all tags ? its possible?

Comment: A regexp correctly matching the opening and closing tags which belong together needs to be context sensitive. Although PREG can do this, it is hard to understand how and the resulting regex isn't easy to understand either. One possible way would be a recursive approach, but this would also be very complicated.

Comment: @FailedDev: I don't fully understand your last regex which matches the content of a `<div>` tag, so may I ask if it also works for nested tags? I'm just interested, not criticising.

Comment: It of course, doesn't work for nested tags. It will throw everything away.